# Laravel wrong view path

Tags: php, laravel, view

When i update a view file i get the view file from the old path.

I have a domain that points to an IP (vps) where i have a laravel installation.

lets call this 123.com and when i visit the domain i get the old view path, a path to the folder where i copied the laravel installation from.

This folder is nammed var/www/111.com/

After the copy i put the source in var/www/123.com/

When i acccess 123.com i get view files from var/www/111.com/ instead of var/www/123.com/

My .conf is like this in the sites-available i have restarted apache many times with sudo service apache2 restart no luck.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 123.com
        ServerAlias www.123.com
    ServerAdmin 123@123.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/123.com/public_html/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The direect IP .conf looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 111.111.dk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/111.111.dk/public/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/111.111.dk/public/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Is the problem with my conf setup in apache2/vps?

I have removed the **.conf** file with **sudo a2dissite 111.111.dk.conf** and restarted with **sudo  /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload** no luck there.

I have also tried with

```
php artisan route:clear

php artisan view:clear
```

No luck there.

Kind regards.

Comment: Yes, definitely there.

Comment: I was thinking that, i have a .conf file that points directly to my ip, but not as a domain, just the ip and then you come to another site, is that the problem?

Comment: did you fix your `route.php` for this new view?

Comment: What do u mean @Sachith where should i change the domain, the view looks after in there?

Comment: If you change a root folder for your project from 111.com to 123.com you have to change it in apache conf as well.

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov i have done that sorry, see update :)

Comment: And you restarted the apache?

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov Check the update my friend. i have tried to reload,restart no lock any ideas? :)

Comment: Looks good to me. No ideas, sorry.

Comment: Try changing `*:80` to listen for the domain (without any subdomains), so `<VirtualHost 123.com:80>`

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy tried it, no luck. i cant understand whats wrong.

Answer (score 11):

I finaly figured it out, it was my config file in laravel, bootstrap/cache/config.php that had wrong paths.

so i ran `php artisan config:cache` and after that everything works :)

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: run `sudo ./artisan config:cache` in the application root path. not the repo path.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the caches - via the terminal:

`php artisan route:clear`

`php artisan view:clear`