# Laravel requesting local file in server (file_put_contents)

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a Laravel app, it was all good until I uploaded to the server, then I got this error

> file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/sites/controltienda/storage/framework/sessions/Gm7GMQ0Lb5c2PSMWatoZZrVf6XvTXxOnF0PJB9RH): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I don't know why it is requesting some file from my local drive which obviously it is not present, I already tried the following:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
```

Without much success. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel wrong view path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215405/laravel-wrong-view-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i keep goin on search and i found this older question [Laravel wrong view path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215405/laravel-wrong-view-path). I ran `php artisan config:cache` and that's all folks.

Thanks for replay.